# Is it possible to create / use the V-disparity map with data from a Time of Flight sensor (instead of normally used RGB-D Stereo Vision approach)?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, disparity-mapping

I am doing my master thesis regarding floor based obstacle detection with a Time of Flight (ToF) camera.

I found out there are alot of applications that use the V- and U- Disparity map to detect and track objects and the ground plane with a stereo vision approach.
They calculate the disparity with the two pictures taken and then create a Histogram of the values so in the V- Disparty map the ground plane is visible as slanted line and obstacles stand out from it.
**So my question is, if it is possible to generate the disparity map from the data from a time of flight camera?** As far as i know those things give me back a point cloud (x,y,z coordinates from each pixel) and a amplitude image of the scene.

So the depth for the disparity in stereo vision is calculated like this:

depth = (baseline * focal length) / disparity)

A ToF camera has an objective and therefore it is using the pin hole approach to calculate the right depth. So is there any posibillity to gain a disparity map with an ToF camera?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: No, you can't generate a disparity map from a time-of-flight camera.

I have not used many time-of-flight cameras, but the ones I have used have given me uint16 matrices. The shape of the matrices were X by Y with the uint16 values corresponding to the distance from the camera in millimeters. This is not a point cloud; it is a depth map.

Since there is only one camera, there is no disparity and thus no disparity map, but I think you know that.

To create a disparity map from the depth map, I assume you could just make up some fake distance between the cameras (baseline) and rearrange your equation from there. So it would be disparity = (fake_baseline * focal_length) / depth. From here you could calculate your U and V disparity maps like usual.

Since your baseline will be a made-up number, I have a hunch that this wouldn't be useful for ground plane detection nor object avoidance. Thus, I think you would be better off just using the depth map from the time-of-flight camera as-is.

I have not tried this before, nor ever used u-disparity maps before, so take my answer with a grain of salt (I could be wrong).

Comment: Okay yes, I see and you're right it's a depth math and not a point cloud. I was just wondering if there is a way to implement this which I've overlooked but yeah since there is only one camera the stereo vision approach cannot be used without creating a error source (fake baseline).
Thank you for your time, Sir. I appreciate it and you helped me a lot!